# Symfony2 The user provider must return a UserInterface object on login

Tags: php, symfony

I'm actually trying to create a login form matching with my database.

The form works well but I've a problem using a `UserRepository`. Symfony gives me the following error:

```
The user provider must return a UserInterface object.
exception 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationServiceException' with message 'The user provider must return a UserInterface object.' in C:\wamp\www\php\Promocast\Symfony\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:101
```

But as you can see below, my user entity is implemented by `UserInterface` so I really don't understand what's the mistake here.

My user entity:

```
    <?php

    namespace Promocast\UtilisateurBundle\Entity;

    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * Promocast\UtilisateurBundle\Entity\ImUser
     * 
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Promocast\UtilisateurBundle\Entity\ImUserRepository")
     */
    class ImUser implements UserInterface
    {

        /**
        * Here all my var and getter/setter
        * ...
        */

        /**
         * Fonctions UserInterface
         * 
         */
        public function eraseCredentials()
        {
        }
        public function getRoles()
        {
            return $this->idrole;
        }
        public function equals(UserInterface $user)
        {
            return $user->getUsername() === $this->login;
        }
        public function getUsername()
        {
            return $this->login;
        }
        public function getSalt()
        {
            return '';
        }

    }
```

My user repository:

```
    <?php

    namespace Promocast\UtilisateurBundle\Entity;

    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
    use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;

    class ImUserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface
    {
        public function loadUserByUsername($login)
        {
            $user = $this->findBy(array("login" => $login));

            if (!$user) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('No user with name "%s" was found.', $login));
            }

            return $user;
        }

        public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
        {
            return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
        }

        public function supportsClass($class)
        {
            return $class === 'Promocast\UtilisateurBundle\Entity\ImUser';
        }
    }
```

And my security.yml:

```
    security:
        encoders:
            Promocast\UtilisateurBundle\Entity\ImUser: plaintext
            #Promocast\UtilisateurBundle\Security\Provider\LoginWebService: plaintext

        role_hierarchy:
            ROLE_USER_SUP:    ROLE_USER
            ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER_SUP
            ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_USER_SUP, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

        providers:
            main:
                entity: { class: PromocastUtilisateurBundle:ImUser }
                #entity: { class: Promocast\UtilisateurBundle\Entity\ImUser, property: login }
                #id: webservice_user_provider


        firewalls:
            dev:
                pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
                security: false
            login:
                pattern:   ^/(login$|register|resetting) 
                anonymous: true                          
            main:
                pattern: ^/                      
                form_login:                      
                    login_path: /login              
                    check_path: /login_check            
                    username_parameter: _login
                    password_parameter: _password
                remember_me:
                    key:         %secret%       
                anonymous:       true           
                provider:        main
                logout:          true            
                logout:
                    path: /logout
                    target: /

        access_control:
            #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
            #- { path: ^/_internal, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
            #- { path: /.*, role: ROLE_USER }
            #- { path: /login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your problem is here:

```
public function loadUserByUsername($login)
{
    $user = $this->findBy(array("login" => $login));
    if (!$user) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('No user with name "%s" was found.', $login));
    }

    return $user;
}
```

`$this->findBy()` is probably returning a cursor/resultset rather than one row as you intended (even if the resultset contains only one row).

Try just using `$this->findOneBy()` instead.

Based on your code, it looks like you are following the cookbook tutorial on [How to load Security Users from the Database (the Entity Provider)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html) - but if you're not, that is a helpful resource in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you solved my problem !

I'm following the cookbook and i figured out that with the dql request my entity repository works fine so i guess the findby just don't work for this kind of use !

One's again thank a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Caveat:  I'm far from an expert on the S2 security system.  I'm just posting what works for me.

There is nothing in your config file that tells the system to use ImUserRepository as a user provider.  So the system is basically trying to use a default provider.  Furthermore, using a repository is problematical at best.  Doctrine repos can only come from Doctrine entity managers so you asking the system to say hey my user class is a doctrine entity therefore I should use a repository and I guess I'll use this entity manager.  Not going to happen.

Make your user provider a service and then inject the entity manager into it.

```
security:
    providers:
        my_provider:
            id: zayso_core.user.provider


    <service id="zayso_core.user.provider" class="Zayso\CoreBundle\Component\User\UserProvider" public="true">
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.accounts_entity_manager" />
        <argument type="string">%zayso_core.user.class%</argument>
    </service>
```

You will probably also want to encode your passwords eventually so:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Zayso\AreaBundle\Component\User\User:
            id: zayso_core.user.encoder


    <service id="zayso_core.user.encoder" class="Zayso\CoreBundle\Component\User\Encoder" public="true">
    </service>
```

And that should get you going.

Comment: could be that but the thing is i call my repository in my user entity :

     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Promocast\UtilisateurBundle\Entity\ImUserRepository")

but thank you for your answer !